# childChanged is not called in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attaching a `.childChanged` on each chat newly downloaded.
When I update the value of a child in firebase console for the first time, the observer is triggered.
Any subsequent update, does not trigger the `.childChanged` observer.
 I put breakpoints on all lines.

Note:
initial data -> `firstName: "Chris"`
updatedData ->  `firstName: "Larry"`

```
//chats of the currentUser
var currentUserChats = [Chat]() {
    didSet(newValue){
      attachChildChangedObserverOn(chat: newValue)
    }
}

var observersArray = [String: UInt]() // chatUID:handle


//attach childChange listener on each chat downloaded
func attachChildChangedObserverOn(chat: Chat) {

    var handle: UInt = 0
    let ref =   DDatabaseRReference.chats.reference().child(chat.chatUID).child("users").child(currentUser.userUID)


    handle = ref.observe(.childChanged, with: {[weak self] (snapshot) in

        self?.observersArray[chat.chatUID] = handle

        guard snapshot.exists() else {return}
        let chatChanged = chat
    })

 }
```

Comment: If you are passing the same value then the observer will not be triggered!

Comment: @SohilR.Memon I am updating using different value, see my updated question.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon  The code is correct. In a previous implementation, I was detaching the listeners in `prepareForReuse` and I totally forgot to comment out that piece of code, hence the reason why childChanged was called only once.